# Pandas: interpolate missing rows and plot multiple series in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I'm looking for pointers to the appropriate docs for accomplishing the analysis task described below with pandas in pylab.  I've previously written python + matplotlib functions that accomplish much of this, but the resulting code is slow and cumbersome to maintain.  It seems like pandas has the capabilities needed but I'm getting bogged down trying to find the right approach and functions.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [6]: df = pd.read_csv("tinyexample.csv", parse_dates=2)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   I                  t       A      B        C     D        E
0  1  08/06/13 02:34 PM  109.40  105.50  124.30  1.00  1930.95
1  1  08/06/13 02:35 PM  110.61  106.21  124.30  0.90  1964.89
2  1  08/06/13 02:37 PM  114.35  108.84  124.30  0.98  2654.33
3  1  08/06/13 02:38 PM  115.38  109.81  124.30  1.01  2780.63
4  1  08/06/13 02:40 PM  116.08  110.94  124.30  0.99  2521.28
5  4  08/06/13 02:34 PM  105.03  100.96  127.43  1.12  2254.51
6  4  08/06/13 02:35 PM  106.73  101.72  127.43  1.08  2661.76
7  4  08/06/13 02:38 PM  111.21  105.17  127.38  1.06  3163.07
8  4  08/06/13 02:40 PM  111.69  106.28  127.38  1.09  2898.73
```

The above is a tiny slice of minute-by-minute readings from a network of radio-connected data loggers. The sample shows ouput from 2 loggers over a 10 minute period.  The 
actual data files have output from dozens of loggers over multiple days.

Column 'I' is the  logger id, 't' is a timestamp, 'A-C' are temperatures, 'D' is a flow rate, and 'E' is an energy rate computed from A, B, and D.

Because of poor radio connectivity **there are missing readings in all loggers at random times**.

Specifically, I want to do something like the following

```
for i in I:
    ## Insert rows for all missing timestamps with interpolated values for A through E
    ## Update a new column 'F' with a cumulative sum of 'E' (actually E/60)
```

Then I want to be able to define a plotting function that allows me to output vertically-aligned strip-chart plots 
similar to those shown in the docs at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html.  I've tried

```
df.plot(subplots=True, sharex=True)
```

which almost does what I need, except that

1. It plots by index number rather than by date.
2. It doesn't create individual plot lines for each logger id.

[image: plot results]

Finally, I'd want to be able to choose a subset of the logger id's and data columns to plot, e.g.

```
def myplot(df, ilist, clist):
    """
    ilist is of the form [ n, m, p, ...] where n, m, and p are logger id's in column 'I'
    clist is a list of column labels.

    Produces stack of strip chart plots, one for each column contain plot lines for each id.
    """
```

**SOLUTION (using Dan Allan's accepted answer -- thanks, Dan)**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def myinterpolator(grp, cols = ['I', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']):
    index = pd.date_range(freq='1min', 
            start=grp.first_valid_index(), 
            end=grp.last_valid_index())
    g1  = grp.reindex(set(grp.index).union(index)).sort_index()
    for col in cols:
        g1[col] = g1[col].interpolate('time').ix[index]
    g1['F'] = g1['E'].cumsum()    
    return g1 


def myplot(df, ilist, clist):
    df1 = df[df['I'].isin(ilist)][clist + ['I']]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(clist))
    for I, grp in df1.groupby('I'):
        for j, col in enumerate(clist):
            grp[col].plot(ax=ax[j], sharex=True)


df = pd.read_csv("tinyexample.csv", parse_dates=True, index_col=1)

df_interpolated = pd.concat([myinterpolator(grp) for I, grp in df.groupby('I')])
myplot(df_interpolated, ilist=[1,4], clist=['F', 'A', 'C'])
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: How do you want your values interpolated? Simple methods like filling forward the last valid option is supported. More advanced methods can be done, but there aren't convenience wrappers in pandas: there's an [open issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4434) with a bit of discussion about interpolation

Comment: @TomAugspurger, linear is fine for this application.

Comment: As linked on my answer below, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18276030/1221924) for one approach to resampling. Perhaps the issue Tom linked above will lead to a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two pieces of this are tricky: interpolation (see Tom's comment) and your desire to plot different sensors in the same subplot. The `subplots=True` keyword is not sufficient for this subtlety; you have to use a loop. This works.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myplot(df, ilist, clist):
    df1 = df[df['I'].isin(ilist)][clist + ['t', 'I']].set_index('t')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(clist))
    for I, grp in df1.groupby('I'):
        for j, col in enumerate(clist):
            grp[col].plot(ax=ax[j], sharex=True)
```

Usage:

```
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t']) # Make sure pandas treats t as times.
myplot(df, [1, 4], ['A', 'B', 'C'])
plt.tight_layout() # cleans up the spacing of the plots
```

[image]

You may not actually *need* interpolation. The above executes even if some data is missing, and the plot lines visually interpolate the data linearly. But if you want actual interpolation -- say for additional analysis -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18276030/1221924).

Comment: The plotting works nicely. Thanks!  I do need the interpolation to get  as much accuracy as possible when summing the energy production, 'E' unless pandas has a built in integrator function that's mathematically equivalent. I looked at your answer for interpolation. Do I need to break the df into separate time series for each logger before interpolating and then stitch them back together?

Comment: Yes. For example, ``df_interpolated = pd.concat([f(grp) for I, grp in df.groupby('I')])`` where f is some function that interpolates your data.